# Automate source generating for Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have a project with multiple modules:

```
parent/
├── module1
└── module2
```

I want to do this:

1. Compile `module1`.
2. Run the program in `module1` to generate some Java code to put into `module2`.
3. Compile `module2`.

The generated code is not supposed to be put into SCM.

What is the best way to do this in Maven?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you generate code the generation should be done in a separate module and never run a program which generates code for another module. Generating will be done in `target`  directory which means it will not being checked in. The question is: Do you have already a tool which can generated the code?

Comment: Yes, I have written several meta programs that generate the code. Currently, I am manually running a script to generate all of the code. With `exec-maven-plugin` and `build-helper-maven-plugin`, I can somewhat automate the process, but it does not integrate well with IntelliJ, so I keep the manual way.

Comment: BTW, the automatically generated code is currently put into `module2/target/generated-sources`, while the manually generated code is put into `module2/src/main/java`.